# How to append an existing delta to the end of current Quill content

Tags: quill

I have stored existing Quill content as JSON in a database. I need to append this to the end of the existing Quill content and have been unable to do it so far.

UpdateContents(delta) adds it to the beginning of the current content and I have not been successful in specifying an insertion point.

I can specify where to insert plain text with InsertText. How can I accomplish this with inserting deltas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a "Concat" reference at https://github.com/quilljs/delta#construction-1 that allows me to combine the two deltas. Here's an implementation that works for my purposes:

```
    var Delta = Quill.import('delta');
    var passedDelta = new Delta(JSON.parse(passedValue));
    var existingDelta = this.get("quill").getContents()
    var combinedDelta = existingDelta.concat(passedDelta);
    this.get("quill").setContents(combinedDelta)
```